# Firewall open ports for vSphere

Tags: networking, firewall, port, vsphere

I need to open ports on a firewall, so that a client can access his VM console through vCenter server's Web Client. I had a look at [this page](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012382) about port description, but I am a little confused.

I already have a port open for the client on a firewall, to access vCenter server's 443 port (https), 9443 (for vSphere PC client), 902 (TCP/UDP) and the client still gets some kind of error related to 902 port being blocked.

Do I have to open port 902 on ESXi hosts and not on vCenter instead? What should I permit as well?

Comment: Unless vCenter is having trouble communicating with the hosts, no. The problem by the sound of it is only between the http client and VC server. What sort of firewall have you got are there logging abilities to confirm it is the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012382) shows that port 902 needs to be open between the vCenter Server (source)  and the ESX(i) host (target) in order to be able to make a remote MKS connection, as you suspected.

[If the above link doesn't work, try [this](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1012382).]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mentioned about accessing virtual machine console using VMware Remote Console through the vSphere Client.

You must do the following things:

**For vCenter Server**

- The firewall must allow the vSphere Client to access vCenter Server on port 443

**For ESXi hosts**

- The firewall must allow the VMRC to access ESXi host on port 902 for VMRC versions before 11.0, and port 443 for VMRC version 11.0 and greater.

You can visit the following pages for more information

- [VMware Remote Console 11.x requires port 443 on ESXi hosts](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76672)
- [Connecting to the Virtual Machine Console Through a Firewall](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-27A340F5-DE98-41A8-AC73-01ED4949EEF2.html)